# Using Results of GIMP Background Remover to Stretch the Background

Tags: gimp

I would like to add the GIMP BG Remover to my repertoire for converting portraits to landscapes (yes I know about outpainting and online bg and fg generators). I remove the background, then take the foreground as a mask to the original image, allowing me to select the foreground and fill it in using GIMP resynthesizer.

Then I stretch the background and paste back the foreground.

The first few steps in this process are for me (perhaps an advanced beginner with GIMP) too tedious. I have to create a png file then open the png along with the original image. Seems to me I should be able to skip this step by having a greater understanding of how masks work.

Any help going straight from the GIMP BG Remover results to my final results will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Yes I know the example I included below has room for improvement.

[image: Case Study Using Gimp BG Remover to Stretch Background]

Comment: Hi. I'm not familiar with that plugin, and I'm not installing it to find out. Sorry. GIMP has its own Foreground Select Tool, which allows you to remove backgrounds. You don't really need anything else. Also for something as simple as a ball, you don't even need that. Select the ball with the ellipse tool, and add a layer mask from the selection.

Comment: I don't undersant why you have to export your image, What do you keep it as a layer?

Comment: you do "need [some]thing else" besides the Foreground Select Tool if you have complex foregrounds and backgrounds.
I "have to export [my] image" because I can't figure out how to move the foreground mask from the BG Removal tool output layer to the original layer. That's the gist of this question-request.
I need the background in one layer and the foreground in the other.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error I have a solution. Turns out the Quick Mask that I've been using applies to all layers, so there's no need (or way) to copy it to other layers. So I create a mask on the Background Remover generated .png, and this mask immediately applied to the original image. Using this mask I select the foreground object on the original and zap it using GIMP Resynthesizer.
If you have a better approach (e.g. a tweak to the plugin), I would love to hear it. I found and installed this plugin using instructions from pixcores.com/2022/12/ai-background-remover-plugin-for-gimp

[image]